# jQuery, and other JS not running when copied from working jsfiddle into local env?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, document-ready

Even when uploaded to my testing server and using DOM ready, scripts seem to be unresponsive. (I'm in Mavericks, Chrome).

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/1361/

Would anyone mind helping me set this up? I have tried so many different variations of DOM ready and haven't had any luck. Something tells me it also has to with:

```
.change
```

I was using that in a code yesterday and it wasn't working too well either. I reseached and found:

```
.bind('change',function)
```

but my implementation didn't work with that either. Anyone got any ideas? Super annoying!

Side question: do I need to be referencing a jQuery library for functions like this or just jQueries involving like ".slide" etc? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
      $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="my image" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your code (HTML, jQuery)? What is it that you *want* it to do? What is it that it's *doing instead*, or what is it *not* doing at all?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console of your server?

Comment: Thanks David. My code is literally the exact same js fiddle code. It's just rendering the html and and when click select a file, I can grab the pic, and it just doesn't show anything. I'd like it to function just like the regular jsfiddle code (display an image).

Comment: @j0861 bunch of different ones depending on the setup but undefined referenceerror "$", unexpected ending on input, etc.

Comment: undefined referenceerror "$" typically means jQuery isn't being loaded.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: and it needs to be for this function, yes? I've referenced it and the link seems to be good?

Comment: When working in local environment I'd suppose `http://` is needed too in the `src` of the `script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you putting the js in the html page? If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/1364/) it doesn't work because I have selected to have the js in the head which is attaching the event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

Put the js in the body and wrap it just like John S said

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // js code here
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Also, make sure you are including the jquery library!

Comment: Does this mean I can't reference the javascript externally? Or I simply put <script src="my.js"></script> in the body?

Comment: You can include it in another file. I think the sum of the issues here were 1) include js library and 2) make sure the element exists in the DOM before attaching the event. Others pointed these out too.